# Saving characters as escaped but having them stay in that exact format in xml java

Tags: java, xml, escaping

my problem is that if I save my string to an xml that contains escaped xml characters, it will escape only some of them. For instance if i save

```
<p id="myParagraph">hello my name is "John"</p>
```

this will successfully escape the p tags but it leaves the quotes. This is especially an issue if i have some kind of html tag that has an id where it must be in quotes. How can I format this to save as

```
id=&quot;myParagraph&quot;
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are currently using?  It will help in answering your question.

Comment: \" is escape character for " in Java?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CDATA to prevent XML processing on text.

```
<somexmltag><![CDATA[<p id="myParagraph">hello my name is "John"</p>]]></somexmltag>
```

This way you don't have to encode your text data.

Comment: If I want to grab this text later, this CDATA will not show?

Comment: Correct. Any parser will load the text inside CDATA without parsing it and your program will not see the CDATA decleration.